# Html javascript высставить точки в поле input

Tags: html, javascript

```
как в поле input можно выставить точки, например для ввода инициалов, сделать такую себе форму, что бы там постоянно были две точки, стояли на втором символе и четвертом
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет плагин для jQuery **[maskedinput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)**.
По ссылке вы найдете примеры его использования. Очень легко настраивается.